# Determine the complexity of the following algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, computer-science, discrete-mathematics

In this algorithm, n is considered the input size:

```
count := 0
i := 1
for i := to n do
  count += i
end for
k := i
while k < 10 do
  k += 1
  count += k
  k *= 2
end while
```

At first, I thought n, but then thought that the while would be log(n) and now I'm a bit confused. Any thoughts would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop is O(n).

Big-O deals with *really **big** values of `n`*. `k` is equal to `n` before the second loop begins. The second loop will only run at all if `k` (and thus `n`) is less than `10`. `10` is in the grand scheme of things a very small number so the second loop doesn't factor in.

Thus the whole thing is O(n).